# Breaking apart a textblock into strings at a new line

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to get the content of a textbox, and split it into an array, and then write each line into a file. It looks something like this:

```
string[] ban = Regex.Split(ImportText.Text, "\r\n");

        foreach (string card in ban)
        {
            if (card != "")
            {
                string banlist = isoStorage.getSettings("banList");
                banlist = "\r\n" + card + banlist;
                isoStorage.changeSettings("banList", banlist);
            }
            ImportText.Text = "";
            updateBanListView();
        }
```

The problem is that textbox doesn't return a new line as \r\n. I've tried \n, \r\n, and even environment.newline. I'm using C# on WP7.

Any ideas on how to split my textbox into an array of lines?

Comment: Try `String.Split(ImportText.Text, Environment.NewLine)`.

Comment: Do you have a `Lines` property for your `Textbox`?

Comment: That's only available in win forms, not WP7 to my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, Windows Phone only uses a carraige return (\r) for a line split in TextBoxes.  Two ways you could go about it are.

```
string[] ban = ImportText.Text.Split('\r');
```

But that may break if they decide to actually use \n in the future.  I've seen another example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/1cfefc85-317d-4d34-8491-0a3ff57505c6/) doing it this way:

```
List<string> ban = new List<string>();
string s;

while ((s = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    ban.Add(s);
}
```

Which feels a bit safter

Comment: `System.Environment.NewLine` should also return the correct character sequence for the Windows Phone platform.

Comment: @SteveGuidi, yes it SHOULD, but it doesn't.  Disclaimer though, I'm not using the Mango SDK, I'm using the older tools.