# Windows Phone - First line of TextBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, newline, windows-phone

I've founded the following code to take the first line from a string:

```
string firstline = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

This does not work because the XAML TextBox uses a \r to represent a linebreak, but Environment.NewLine is \r\n.

Is there a defined constant string for NewLine in WindowsPhone/XAML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting on "\r", I found an example in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665171/breaking-apart-a-textblock-into-strings-at-a-new-line).

Hope this helps!

Comment: No this does not work. I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException because there is no conversion from &#13; to \r

Comment: Hmm. I haven't actually tried this since I'm at work, but can you split on '\r'? I found this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665171/breaking-apart-a-textblock-into-strings-at-a-new-line

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Did you set **MultiLine** property to **true**?

**Environment.NewLine** defines
A string containing "**\r\n**" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "**\n**" for Unix platforms.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which MultiLine property? There's only a AcceptsReturn property. I'm using the default TextBox (System.Windows.Controls.TextBox).

Comment: Yes, but Silverlight's TextBox (including the Windows Phone version) is funky, it uses \r. And this is published behavior now.